# Wrong data (junk or 0s) returned from pointer array member of struct

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to read some float values as an array to a struct member as shown below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_IN 10

typedef struct S_t S_t;

struct S_t {
    float *sptr; 
    uint32_t ns;
};


S_t *getInputS(char *sdfile) 
{
FILE *inSFP;
float fvls[MAX_IN];
static S_t inS;
int n;

inSFP = fopen(sdfile, "r");
if (inSFP == NULL) {
    printf("\nFailed to open input file...!!!\n");
}
else {
    n = 0;
    while (fscanf(inSFP, "%f", &fvls[n]) != EOF) {
    printf("fvls[%d] = %f\n", n, fvls[n]);
    n++;
    }
    printf("\nScanned all inputs....\n");
    inS.ns = (uint32_t) n;
    inS.sptr = (float *) malloc(n * sizeof(float));
    inS.sptr = fvls;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("inS.sptr[%d] = %f\n", i, inS.sptr[i]);

    printf("\nInput read from file %s....\n", sdfile);

    fclose(inSFP);
    printf("\nClosed file...");
}
return &inS;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
S_t *inpS = malloc(sizeof(*inpS));
inpS->sptr = malloc(MAX_IN * sizeof(inpS->sptr));
S_t *outS = malloc(sizeof(*outS));
outS->sptr = malloc(MAX_IN * sizeof(outS->sptr));
static uint32_t n;

char *inFN = argv[1];
char *outFN = argv[2];

inpS = getInputS(inFN);
printf("\nContent from main : \n");
n = inpS->ns;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%f", *(inpS->sptr + i));
    // printf("%f", inpS->sptr[i]);
printf("\nS structure updated (ns = %d)....\n", n);

return 0;
}
```

This returns the following:

```
fvls[0] = 0.430000
fvls[1] = 0.563210
fvls[2] = 0.110000
fvls[3] = 1.230000
fvls[4] = -0.034000

Scanned all inputs....
inS.sptr[0] = 0.430000
inS.sptr[1] = 0.563210
inS.sptr[2] = 0.110000
inS.sptr[3] = 1.230000
inS.sptr[4] = -0.034000

Input read from file in.txt....

Closed file...
Content from main :
-0.0000000.0000000.0000000.000000-nan
S structure updated (ns = 5)....

Input values (Original Input):
[0.000000, 0.000000, -0.000000, 0.000000, -0.000000]
```

The values are indeed read from the input file by the function `getInputS()` correctly, but on return the member `sptr`'s values are returned incorrectly.
I am using a static variable of type `S_t` to store the values so that the value is retained. Inspite of that, the values seem to have lost! What am I doing wrong here? How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the input file?

Comment: It's a simple text file with values `0.43 0.56321 0.11 1.23 -0.034`.

Comment: `inS.sptr = fvls;` what happens to fvls when you exit the function scope?

Comment: You have allocated memory, but you haven't copied any data, instead, you overwrite the return value of malloc.

Comment: `fvals` is kind of temporary variable that is destroyed when the function is exited. I just wanted it for counting the array numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
inS.sptr = (float *) malloc(n * sizeof(float));
```

you cause `sptr` to point to a malloc'ed region of just the right size for your inputs.
That's good.
But in the very next line:

```
inS.sptr = fvls;
```

you throw the malloc'ed pointer away, overwriting it with a pointer to the local `fvls` array, which is going to disappear when this function returns.

Stated another way: when you store a pointer in a pointer variable, it's just like storing any other value in any other variable.  Any time you do something like this:

```
a = b;
a = c;
```

you are throwing away the effect of the first assignment, and when you're done, all `a` is left holding is the value of `c`.  It's no different when `a` is a pointer variable and `b` and `c` are two different pointer values.

Whenever you work with pointers, you have to keep clear in your mind the distinction between *the pointer* and *what the pointer points to*.  In your `getInputS` function, you have to worry about both: you have to set *the pointer* `sptr` to point to valid storage to contain the values you've read, *and* you have to set *what the pointer points to* to be those values.  When you say

```
inS.sptr = (float *) malloc(n * sizeof(float));
```

you're setting *the pointer*.  But when you say

```
inS.sptr = fvls;
```

you're resetting *the pointer* to something else.  But you never get around to setting *what the pointer points to* (the first, malloc'ed pointer, that is) at all.

And, to be clear, the line

```
inS.sptr = fvls;
```

copies *the pointer*, it does *not* copy the pointed-to data, which is what you need at this point.

To fix this, either:

1. Copy data from `fvls` to `sptr` (in place of the line `inS.sptr = fvls`).  You can call `memcpy`, or you can use a loop repeatedly assigning `sptr[i] = fvls[i]`.
2. Get rid of `fvls`, initialize `sptr` to `malloc(MAX_IN * sizeof(float));`, read directly into `sptr`, and then at the end, if you want to try to minimize wasted space, call `realloc` to reallocate `sptr` down to just big enough for the number of values you actually read.

Comment: Okay. Understood your 2nd suggestion. Could you explain "copying" here?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit Copy each float from `fvls` to `sptr`. Either iterate and assign each element of `fvls` to `sptr` or use a function like `memcpy` or `memmove`.

Comment: @skrowten_hermit Also, note that, in `main`, you allocate `inpS` and its members. But, you throw away this with: `inpS = getInputS(inFN);` [a memory leak]. And, the return value of `getInputS` is a `static`, so less flexible. I'd either pass `main`'s pointer to the function or have the function do _all_ the allocation (i.e. eliminate the `static` variable).

Comment: @skrowten_hermit See updated answer, or alex01011's comment.

Comment: @CraigEstey Yours is a valuable input. I have made the modifications you have suggested too.